# Why don't GWT launch configurations lookup sources in dependency projects by default?

Tags: maven, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

Why there's a difference in `Default` `Source Lookup Path` between `GWT` and `java` launch configurations?

In multi-module projects instead of containing projects, the `Default` folder contains the class folders of those projects!

It causes "Source not found" errors when the debugger steps into a dependency project.

I know I can add projects manually. Just want to know why this difference is needed.

[image]

The only project in the list is the associated with the `.launch`.

Answer (score 0):

GWT needs '.java' source files of dependencies to be able to compile (translate to js) while the Java launcher needs only '.class' compiled files.

I suppose you know GWT has a different way to manage dependencies (through modules within the same project), which is good for some advanced GWT practices like loading a module's js lazily (this feature doesn't work with "foreign" libs/projects).

So this could also be an answer for why eclipse GWT doesn't suppose you will have more projects (but more modules instead)

Finally if you really have an independent GWT lib that you're maintaining this is an issue as you said.

Comment: In classpath. But I'm asking about source lookup.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Then it's an eclipse integration issue you might want to report (of not already done). I suppose you know GWT has a different way to manage dependencies (through modules), which is good for some advanced GWT practices like loading a module lazily (this feature doesn't work with "foreign" libs/projects).
So this could also be an answer